# Trigger on DOM text changed

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im developing some web-automatization tool (C# but this topic is not abou it..).
Tool unsing WebBrowser as a browser and connect to some web-site.

Web site has dynamic content, it updates once per second. Web site using setTimeout to update its content. Then data resopnsed web site update content inside DOM element (table). Its delete 3 old rows and insert 3 new rows.

#### My target is to make a trigger for this event.

I checked and the website doesn't use `document.write`.  As I understand there are some ways the site can modify content. First is `innerHTML` property, but table has 4 rows , site dont update/delete first row. So another way is **appendChild** and **removeChild** its more real.
So my question is how i can trigger this action?

As i know it possible to define my own funcs for DOM element. So how i can redefine appendChild and removeChild methods?

Possible something like this?:

```
var realRC = contentTable.removeChild;
contentTable.removeChild = function(el){
alert("Trigged!");
realRC(el);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean trigger when you say "trig".

### Triggering it

In browsers timeouts and intervals all have IDs, you can clear them but you can't trigger it directly. The best bet would be looking for setTimeout/setInterval statements and replicating them.

### Listening to the event

Anyway, there is a dirty way and a clean way. Let's assume you have access to your table in:

```
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');
```

#### The clean way would be using DOM [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
// Example from MDN
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type); // here you'll get the changes
  });    
});
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

#### The dirty way would be dirty checking

It's better supported and more stable since observers are really new and there are still issues.
Every 16 miliseconds check if the `.innerHTML` value of the table changed.

```
var oldHTML = "";
setTimeout(function(){
    if(target.innerHTML !== oldHTML){
        changed(); // changed is a function that you define and notify
    }
},16);
```

If there are HTML changes like position/etc you can use `.textContent` instead.

Honestly, the dirty way is simpler and more stable - but uglier. Still I'd go for it.

Comment: It's not slow enough to make a difference though :)

Comment: also note that mutation observers are very new, and only supported in the most modern of browsers (IE11) etc

Comment: but its impossible to replace appendChild methond in DOM? Its would be the best way

Comment: .. again i need to make a tool for IE 9+ not 11+ :(

Comment: Yep, dirty checking works though. I suggest you dirty check and then add the new values to a set. Good luck!

Comment: And something else: Im trying this code: var dataTable = document.getElementById("event_1538171");
var realAppendChild = dataTable.appendChild;


dataTable.appendChild = function(node)
{
    console.log("trigged!");
    realAppendChild(node);
    return node;
}

Comment: Mozilla says: [18:44:44.778] TypeError: 'appendChild' called on an object that does not implement interface Node. @ Scratchpad/1:17

Comment: It's `realAppendChild.apply(dataTable,node)` to preserve context. Anyway - if you have other questions please ask them in separete question threads. If this solved your issue please consider accepting this answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin Gruenbaum solve it)
Im post this here for more readable!

```
var dataTable = document.getElementById("event_1538016");

dataTable.appendChild = function(node)
{
    console.log("trigged!");
    document.appendChild.apply(dataTable,[node]); // args is array!!
    return node;
}
```

works perfectly on mozilla! Im hope it will works on IE9+

Comment: I don't understand... you took my solution from the comment (which is unreliable by the way) and then post it as your own answer 10 minutes later.

Comment: no no! Its not my solution! It yours! but im make node as array)) sorry. Im will accept your answer.

Comment: It's not about accepting my solution, I only answer here to help. You might want to lurk around and read up on how asking/answering works here. You can also check the [help].

Comment: Sorry, but im a noob here, and dont know all rules of posting. Im will read help center... Thanks again)